# Media silence during do not disturb

Tags: settings, 7.1-nougat

When i turn my phone to silent now it goes to do not disturb mode and it silence media also
How can i make my phone silent and also be able to listen to media on my phone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With android 7 the do not disturb mode has changed. I do not know of anyway (at this time) to change the behaviour of the dnd mode.
You can, however, instead of turning on dnd simply switch to the priority mode. If you have not configured any priority contacts or anything like that it does behave exactly like the pre-android-7 dnd mode including normal media playback.

Comment: The problem with priority that it will make it vibrate and i dont want vibration it can be annoying,,, i hate this feature

Comment: how to switch to the priority mode? I searched it in settings, but didn't found anything relevant